# How to use cupy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=None, strides=None)

Tags: python, shapes, cupy, stride

I was using:

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view
```

with a 1D-array and two parameters (the array and the length of the subset n) to slice it into slices of n elements (n < 1D-array.shape, of course)

I think I can go faster with cupy and I started with:

```
cupy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=None, strides=None)
```

Documentation is [here](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/v12.0.0b3/reference/generated/cupy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html).

Unfortunately, I cannot manage to run such a simple code:

```
import cupy as cp
x  = [4,2,1,1,1,2,3,4]
y = cp.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=None, strides=2)
print(y)  # expecting a 2D-array of size 7, 2
```

I get:

```
runfile('C:/Users/didie/.spyder-py3/untitled2.py', wdir='C:/Users/didie/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\spyder-cf\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\didie\.spyder-py3\untitled2.py:28
    y = cp.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=None, strides=2)

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\spyder-cf\lib\site-packages\cupy\lib\stride_tricks.py:35 in as_strided
    shape = x.shape if shape is None else tuple(shape)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

It may not be hard to solve...

**EDIT**: new code

```
x  = cp.array([4,2,1,1,1,2,3,4])
y = cp.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, None, strides=2)
print(y)  # expecting a 2D-array of size 7, 2
```

leading to:

```
runfile('C:/Users/didie/.spyder-py3/untitled2.py', wdir='C:/Users/didie/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\spyder-cf\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\didie\.spyder-py3\untitled2.py:27
    y = cp.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, None, strides=2)

  File ~\miniconda3\envs\spyder-cf\lib\site-packages\cupy\lib\stride_tricks.py:36 in as_strided
    strides = x.strides if strides is None else tuple(strides)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found, in case somebody is looking for it (l being the window):

```
y = cp.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=(x.shape[0] - l + 1, l), strides=x.strides + (x.strides[-1],))
```

Based on: https://rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html

Answer (score 1):

CuPy's functions in general only accepts `cupy.ndarray`s. You need to pass `x` as `cupy.ndarray` instead of list.

Comment: Thank you. Great catch, I changed the code to start with a cupy array, but I still fail...

Comment: Here is the solution I found, in case somebody is looking for it (l being the window):

y = cp.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=(x.shape[0] - l + 1, l), strides=x.strides + (x.strides[-1],))